Server restore issue
I have windows image backup so I want restore this backup with windows server backup and while restoring backup I am facing issue like : system writer corrupted and unreadable.
Please help  how to fix this actually my server was AD server so there no chance to demote and promote also because there have some configured
Please help

Start the server to the Recovery Environment and initiate a System Image Restore from there.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-recovery-environment--windows-re--technical-reference
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc755163(v=ws.11)
